# Using Low Variables & P&T Pill in a Conditional

Tags: pixelandtonic, low-variables, low

Having a bit of a weird problem happening with P&T pill field inside Low Variables.

When I used this code:

```
{if "{lv_metasocial_meta_title_display}" == "title_site_name"} | {lv_general_site_name}{/if}
```

It doesn't render out the `{lv_general_site_name}` variable. Moving this outside of the conditional makes it appear.

The options inside the Pill field are:

```
title_only : Meta Data Title Only
title_site_name : Meta Data Title and Site Name
```

Changing the pill values, and also resubmitting the variable multiple times doesn't make this work.

What could be causing this?

I also tried changing the tag to using the Low Variables Single tag, but it throws this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Low_fieldtype_bridge::get_setting() in /.../system/expressionengine/third_party/low_variables/mod.low_variables.php on line 148
```

So I've had to just use it as the field name itself, which outputs fine outside of the conditional due to Low Variables Parse tag being wrapped around it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure **Early Parsing is enabled** for that Pill variable, then use this syntax:

```
{if lv_metasocial_meta_title_display == "title_site_name"}
```

...which is EllisLab's recommended syntax for conditionals.

Comment: I did try setting the early parsing on it, but after trying all the different ways of adding a var in to a conditional "{var}", {var}, var. Was a long day! Even after doing this though it still didn't work. I forgot to mention it was in an embed as well, so I just added the {exp:low_variables:parse} tag inside the embed. Which is odd, because all the other low variable vars were working without this, just not the one in the conditional.